# using jquery with browserify

Tags: jquery, node.js, browserify

I am trying to use jQuery with browserify with the module jquery-browserify. 
I required the module in my client.js script as such:

```
    var $ = require('jquery-browserify');
```

and when I run my node server, after i've ran browserify, i get a "window is not defined" error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you were trying to use this inside of node and not in a browser, right?

Comment: Browserify is to be used in a browser.

Comment: Perhaps you have to pass a reference to the window object: var $ = require('jquery-browserify')(window);

Comment: Try installing locally jquery "npm install jquery --save-dev" and use it "var $ = require('jquery');" instead of "jquery-browserify".

Answer (score 5):

jQuery is now CommonJS compliant, as of version 2.1.0

Comment: This was so long ago I don't expect a response, but whatever. How does this work. I jave jQuery 2.10 module from npm, but when I create a module and pass it in using browserify, I cannot use jquery in that module. I see a lot of comments saying it is commonJS compliant, and nothing on how to use it.

Comment: Interesting, could you post an example on GitHub? I've found ```var $ = require('jquery')``` to work pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

Browserify can process CommonJS modules as well as AMD modules with the `deamdify` transform so now there should be no need to use a shim.

To be clear I only noticed AMD support in JQuery 2.0.0

Comment: Too bad this question was asked in 2012. This is probably why they made those.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery was not CommonJS compliant, i.e. it didn't export itself via `module.exports = $` until `2.1.0`.

Therefore you needed to shim it via [browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim).

`browserify-shim` will **shim any version of jquery or any other non-CommonJS library** like Zepto on the fly.
Details on how to set this up are included in the readme.

As an alternative you could have also used [jquery-browserify](https://github.com/jmars/jquery-browserify), but then you would be tied to the jQuery version that this module made CommonJS compliant.

Comment: it is commonsJS compliant as of 2.1.0