# How / why to switch from <script> includes to npm installs?

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js

I have a VueJS project that uses npm to manage all the Vue stuff (vue-resource, router, Vuex etc). But in my index.html file I've also got a bunch of other stuff included via script tags:

- Bootstrap
- jQuery
- Tween

Would it be beneficial to include them via NPM instead, so they are (presumably?) bundled in the main build file? If so, how exactly do I do this?

Comment: Yes. Use a bundler like WebPack or Browserify.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: This question is actually more interesting and meaningful than it looks. Even though NPM is the modern standard for Javascript development, there is definitely no use in it, as opposed to a bunch of `script` tags pointing at CDN, in some cases.

Comment: It's too broad. There are at least 10 different "bundlers" out there, each with different requirements and commands, and which one is the "best" cannot be objectively defined. "How can I bundle scripts" is a question which would really require a tutorial, which are many on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependencies need to be bundled up into one normal javascript file in order for a browser to be able to read it.

In your project directory, you'll run these commands:

`npm install bootstrap`

`npm install jquery`

`npm install tween`

And wherever you want, run this command:

`npm install --global browserify`

Then create a javascript file (app.js) in your project directory like so:

```
require('bootstrap')
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
window.TWEEN = require('tween.js')
// rest of code...
```

And save that file. Then run the following command:

`browserify app.js -o bundle.js`

Then in your html file, have this script tag:

`<script src="bundle.js"></script>`

You'll need to rerun that browserify command every time you make a change to `app.js`, so take a look at [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/).

Comment: In the specific case of jQuery, you may run into some issues with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379692/using-jquery-with-browserify

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've run the npm commands, and tried to include the 'require' statements in my already existing main.js file that I believe gets compiled by browserify along with everything else, but this results in 'jquery is not defined' in the console.

Comment: Browserify does not bundle libraries into the global scope, so if you want to do that you need to attach it to `window` like so: `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');` you should then be able to use it as normal.

Comment: Taking from what @craig_h said, in my example that would mean this: in app.js after all the requires just add his line: `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');`

Comment: @SamuelReid gulp isn't the only option, in this case, a simple npm script would do. However, if he's already using a build tool for vue-related stuff, it would be best to run browserify with that.

Comment: I was thinking of using `gulp watch` in order to automatically browserify for him whenever he saves a change to his javascript file.

Comment: Thanks, once I got the correct imports (tweenjs instead of tween, and bootstrap@3 instead of bootstrap...) it worked great with these 3 lines: `window.TWEEN = require('tween.js');
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');`